# The minimal sufficient statistic is not unique, but the minimal sufficient partition is unique, what does this mean?

Tags: probability, statistics

Can anyone help to illustrate the statement with some examples?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you have a biased coin with a probability $p$ of showing heads and you flip it three times independently.

There are eight possible outcomes (one is: tails then heads then tails), but the minimal sufficient partition for $p$ divides the results into four parts: three heads, two heads and a tail in any order, a head and two tails in any order, and three tails.

There are several minimal statistics for $p$, such as the total number of heads, the total number of tails, the number of heads minus the number of tails, or the average number of heads per flip.   They each lead to the same partition of the possible outcomes.